# Скроллбар криво работает из-за ширины окна браузера

Tags: css

Скроллбар работает криво внутри внутри блока **text-block**.
При ширине экрана **1920px** скроллбар исчезает, а при уменьшении окна браузера не прокручивает до конца текст. Чтобы скроллбар до конца прокрутил текст, нужно уменьшить ширину окна браузера до минимума.

**Как заставить скроллбар нормально работать на любой ширине окна браузера?**

```css
.Main-block{
overflow:hidden;
height:250px;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 30% 69%; 
border:1px solid black;
}

.child-img-1{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.text-block{
position:relative;
overflow-x:hidden;  
overflow-y:auto;
}

.child-text{
text-align:center;      
font-size:18px;
font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="Main-block">
<img class="child-img-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/4fLYYJs/scale-1200.webp">

<div class="text-block">

<p class ="child-text">
Учитывая ключевые сценарии поведения, внедрение современных методик в значительной степени обусловливает важность переосмысления внешнеэкономических политик. В целом, конечно, новая модель организационной деятельности позволяет выполнить важные задания по разработке переосмысления внешнеэкономических политик. Мы вынуждены отталкиваться от того, что консультация с широким активом предполагает независимые способы реализации своевременного выполнения сверхзадачи. Каждый из нас понимает очевидную вещь: существующая теория является качественно новой ступенью переосмысления внешнеэкономических политик. Также как консультация с широким активом предоставляет широкие возможности для как самодостаточных, так и внешне зависимых концептуальных решений.
Но сделанные на базе интернет-аналитики выводы, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского типа политической культуры, будут объективно рассмотрены соответствующими инстанциями. В рамках спецификации современных стандартов, сторонники тоталитаризма в науке призывают нас к новым свершениям, которые, в свою очередь, должны быть своевременно верифицированы. В своём стремлении повысить качество жизни, они забывают, что семантический разбор внешних противодействий требует от нас анализа укрепления моральных ценностей. Но убеждённость некоторых оппонентов играет определяющее значение для поэтапного и последовательного развития общества! Безусловно, убеждённость некоторых оппонентов предопределяет высокую востребованность укрепления моральных ценностей. Предварительные выводы неутешительны: реализация намеченных плановых заданий требует от нас анализа стандартных подходов. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий обеспечивает актуальность новых предложений КОНЕЦ КОНЕЦ КОНЕЦ КОНЕЦ!!!
</p> 

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.Main-block{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:250px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 69%; 
    border:1px solid black;
    }
    
    .child-img-1{
    width:100%;
    height: inherit;
    }
    
    .text-block{
    position:relative;
    overflow-x:hidden;  
    overflow-y:auto;
    }
    
    .child-text{
    text-align:center;      
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:arial;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Main-block">
        <img class="child-img-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/4fLYYJs/scale-1200.webp">
        
        <div class="text-block">
        
        <p class ="child-text">
        Учитывая ключевые сценарии поведения, внедрение современных методик в значительной степени обусловливает важность переосмысления внешнеэкономических политик. В целом, конечно, новая модель организационной деятельности позволяет выполнить важные задания по разработке переосмысления внешнеэкономических политик. Мы вынуждены отталкиваться от того, что консультация с широким активом предполагает независимые способы реализации своевременного выполнения сверхзадачи. Каждый из нас понимает очевидную вещь: существующая теория является качественно новой ступенью переосмысления внешнеэкономических политик. Также как консультация с широким активом предоставляет широкие возможности для как самодостаточных, так и внешне зависимых концептуальных решений.
        Но сделанные на базе интернет-аналитики выводы, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского типа политической культуры, будут объективно рассмотрены соответствующими инстанциями. В рамках спецификации современных стандартов, сторонники тоталитаризма в науке призывают нас к новым свершениям, которые, в свою очередь, должны быть своевременно верифицированы. В своём стремлении повысить качество жизни, они забывают, что семантический разбор внешних противодействий требует от нас анализа укрепления моральных ценностей. Но убеждённость некоторых оппонентов играет определяющее значение для поэтапного и последовательного развития общества! Безусловно, убеждённость некоторых оппонентов предопределяет высокую востребованность укрепления моральных ценностей. Предварительные выводы неутешительны: реализация намеченных плановых заданий требует от нас анализа стандартных подходов. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий обеспечивает актуальность новых предложений КОНЕЦ КОНЕЦ КОНЕЦ КОНЕЦ!!!
        </p> 
        
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: или можно блоку текса унаследовать ширину тоже сработает

Comment: Из-за чего была проблема?

Comment: Ну как я могу судить, текст пытался обтекать картинку, поэтому высота блока текста увеличивалась относительно картинки, тк у картинки высота 100% - её блок уходил за родительский ниже. поэтому ширину лучше наследовать, а не использовать %. Вообще для более ясной картины возьмите свой старый код, откройте в браузере - войдите в консоль разработчика нажав - F12 - Elements - и пройдите по каждому блоку кода, и посмотрите поведение на разных разрешениях этих самых блоков. думаю вопросы сами собой исчезнут :)